# akka where messages are processed?

Tags: akka

i read in akka documentation about `dispatchers`. But i do not understood correctly, for example, if i have 2 actors, which run with `default-disptacher`. I send a few messages in actors, ok, then `default-dispatcher` get message from mailbox, and ??? where message are processed in `default-dispatcher` or where? If i run in actor (with `context.disptacher` of cource) some block operation, and configure dispatcher with 1 thread in thread pool, this will stop the message processing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain it the best I can.

The `dispatchers` just schedule the [code in the actor system](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Dispatchers).

Following your example, if your actor sends a message to an actor (as you say to its mailbox), at certain point in the future the dispatcher will assign a thread to the actor to get that message and run it.
The code always run in the actors you define, but in the threads provided by the dispatcher.

And in the case you define your own dispatcher with a `fixed-pool-size = 1` and block that thread, the dispatcher will recover that thread after the amount of time defined in `keep-alive-time`.